# VBA, Fill up/down rows to align with last row

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to delete rows till it meets my last row OR fill down rows to align with last row.

Sometimes my sheet will be like below where I need to delete rows to align with my last row number.:

[image]

However sometimes my sheet will be like below, where I need to fill down other columns:

[image]

Is there a function that can do this? I am finding it hard to determine when to fill up or fill down.

Thanks

Comment: If you have picked the 7th column as one identifier then you should pick another as a second identifier and calculate the last row in both of them and act according to the difference between their last rows. If you have formulas in those empty cells, you will need to use `Find` with `xlValues`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please test the next code. It assumes that the reference column will be the seventh one and the one to check the 0 formulas value to be the sixth one. Your picture does not contain the columns header...

```
Sub DeleteRowsOrFillDownDiscontinuous()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, lastR1 As Long, lastCol As Long

 Set sh = ActiveSheet
 lastR = sh.Range("F" & rows.count).End(xlUp).row
 lastR1 = Range("E" & rows.count).End(xlUp).row
 lastCol = sh.cells(lastR1, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column

 If lastR < lastR1 Then
    sh.rows(lastR + 1 & ":" & lastR1).EntireRow.Delete xlUp
 ElseIf lastR > lastR1 Then
    sh.Range("A" & lastR1, "E" & lastR1).AutoFill _
        Destination:=sh.Range("A" & lastR1, sh.Range("E" & lastR))
    sh.Range("G" & lastR1, "AG" & lastR1).AutoFill _
       Destination:=sh.Range("G" & lastR1, "AG" & lastR)
    sh.Range("AI" & lastR1, sh.cells(lastR1, lastCol)).AutoFill _
       Destination:=sh.Range("AI" & lastR1, sh.cells(lastR, lastCol))
 Else
    MsgBox "Nothing te be processed. Everything aligned..."
 End If
End Sub
```

**Edited:**

Adapted the code for F:F column as reference, AH:AH not changeable, too and existing columns to be processed after AH Column.

Please test it and send some feedback.

Comment: Thanks for this. In my example data, Column F or Column 6  ends at row 4248, and my other columns end at 4250. This code seems to fill down my column F with the last row value but it should be delete 2 rows to meet the last row. Does that help?

Comment: @excelguy Which of the two mentioned columns is the one which should be considered as reference. The one not needed to be modified. The one ending in 2.6 in your picture... The 7th in your picture. Do you want it to be column F:F? If yes, the code can be easily adapted... When you say **"my other columns"** what do you mean? **Which of them**? In your picture, the neighbor columns have a different length. Are there different length for what you name **"my other columns"**?

Comment: @excelguy You do not say anything... I adapted the code as I could understood from your comment, respectively, to consider the reference cell F:F.

Comment: In my spreadsheet columns  F and AH will always be the one not to be modified. All other columns in my sheet should follow these ones whether it is deleting or filling down. Does that help?

Comment: Now I am driving. Are there other columns after AH column?

Comment: Yes there are columns after.

Comment: @excelguy  Adapted the code to process the sheet as you explained in your last comments. But I cannot stop myself saying that you should state all that in your question. How could you imagine that somebody will understand which columns to be unchanged, if your pictures did not reveal anything. from this point of view? Please, test the updated code and confirm that it works as you need. If not, please clearly describe what does it against it should do.

Comment: hey, its working although I get`AutoFill method Range of Class Failed` on line `sh.Range("A" & lastR1, sh.Cells(lastR1, 5)).AutoFill _
        Destination:=sh.Range("A" & lastR1, sh.Cells(lastR, 5)` in cases where it is aligned. Is this error  because the last row already aligned?

Comment: @excelguy Yes, because of that. I will adapt the code to also deal with such a situation... **Adapted**.

Answer (score 2):

keeping in mind the well known caveats of the use of `UsedRange`, you could give it a try

```
Dim lastRow As Long
With ActiveSheet ' <- change it to your actual sheet reference
    With .UsedRange
        lastRow = .Rows(.Rows.Count)
    End With
End With
```